# Popup window from pageReference

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com, controller-extension

I'm trying to open popup window but I can't.

```
pagereference ps=new pagereference('/apex/Popupnewpage');
return ps;
```

Comment: You cannot open a popup from apex. This needs to be done in the VF page using JS. All you can do is redirect the entire page

Comment: Thanks @Eric, Is there any possible to open new window via page reference?

Comment: No. As Eric said, PageReference is handled at the server level and you can only open popups at the client (JS) level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot open popup window from controller.

You can either use commandbutton and use `oncomplete` method to open a popup

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!callMethod}" oncomplete="window.open('<url>','_blank','height=400,location=no,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=1', 1)">
```

or commandLink to open a popup window

```
<apex:commandLink
value="Save" 
id="cmd1"  
target="_blank"  
action="{!callMethod}" 
onclick=" "  />
```

Comment: Thanks Guys for helping.  Is there any possible open new window and auto closed with page reference?

Comment: Again, that can only be possible from visualforce or javacript